# Identify unnecessary inputs of NN

Tags: neural-networks

Lately I've been wondering.
Is there's a way to locate redundant/unnecessary/misleading inputs by analysis of weights in the first layer?

Comment: I don't think so as an input having higher weight-age will definitely get reflected in 2 or more nodes as the input with max influence..also even if you eliminate seemingly unnecessary inputs it might lead to under-fitting...Map reduction is a controlled technique to remove redundant inouts

Answer (score 2):

An interesting way to check for redundancy not only in the first layer but in any layer is to see the weights of you neuron. Let's consider the input layer: The nodes that are connected with the weights that have high values are the most important for your NN performance and in other words your input to these nodes in what mostly makes sense for your task.

If you are in Keras, you can use the `get_weights method()`. You may have a look [here](https://keras.io/layers/about-keras-layers/).